# Свой макет для пункта меню в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-menu, drawerlayout, android-navigation-view

Хочу использовать свой макет пункта меню для **Navigation Drawer**. Во всех примерах, что я нашел это делается довольно просто. В `item` добавляется ссылка на кастомный макет.

```
<item
    android:actionLayout="@layout/test_menu_item"
    android:id="@+id/nav_custom"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Кастомный пункт меню"/>
```

У меня это почему-то работает только для обычного меню, при условии, что такой элемент будет размещен в ActionBar. Для **бокового** меню вообще не работает, кто-нибудь знает почему?

Comment: Как по мне, так проще в DrawerLayout последним элементом кинуть FrameLayout и делать с этим фрагментом, что угодно. 
К примеру, сделать, чтобы в фрагменте отображался список. Ну а в этот список прогружать кастомные айтэмы. Должна красота получиться.

Comment: @YaPV, я хочу сохранить возможности и функционал обычного меню. Но для некоторых айтемов нужны кастомные макеты, чтобы отразить дополнительную информацию.